# How to parse a custom Ruby struct from JSON

Tags: ruby, json

I've got an entity that inherits its behavior from Struct.  It instantiates like this:

`Entity.new(id: 'asdf', name: 'bill', hair: 'brown')`

When I coerce the struct to json, it loks like this:

`#<struct Entity id=\"asdf\", name=\"bill\", 
hair=\"brown\">"`

EDIT: ^^ ignore this. I was trying to keep things vague, but here's a straight copy/paste from my irb session:

`"\"#<struct SorrisoEntity::EmailMessage recipient_email=nil, sender_email=\\\"poo@aol.com\\\", subject_line=nil, body=nil>\""`

When I coerce it to JSON, it doesn't throw an error.  But when I try to a "JSON.parse" call, I get this error:

`JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '"#<struct Entity id=\"asdf\", name=\"bill\", hair=\"brown\">"`

Why Ruby won't marshall the custom struct appropriately?

Comment: That's not JSON. How are you trying to convert?

Comment: It looks like `to_s` not to JSON

Comment: OK.  Just popped in the true output instead of the more general code I had provided originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not documented, but I had to read the ruby source code for `json` and its test to get this, you need to manually `require 'json/add/struct'` and pass the arguments `:create_additions => true` to get this working, as shown below:

```
Entity = Struct.new('Entity', :id, :name, :hair)
entity = Entity.new("asdf", "bill", "brown")
# => #<struct Struct::Entity id={"id"=>"asdf", "name"=>"bill", "hair"=>"brown"}, name=nil, hair=nil>
require 'json/add/struct'
entity.to_json
# => "{\"json_class\":\"Struct::Entity\",\"v\":[\"asdf\",\"bill\",\"brown\"]}" 
new_entity = JSON.parse(entity.to_json, :create_additions => true)
# => #<struct Struct::Entity id="asdf", name="bill", hair="brown"> 
new_entity.name
# => "bill"
```